# Insert dynamic rows to a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

How will I insert rows (which are dynamic) to a single column concatenated by space to a temp table. I'm using SQL Server 2005.

Ex. `LetterTable`:

```
LetterID LetterRow
    1        a
    2        b
    3        c
    4        d
    5        e
```

to insert to a temp table like

`#TempTable`:

```
LetterID LetterRow
    1     a b c d e
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

well I don't quite understand, why your LetterID equals 1 in first example, but you can try this (solution like this is useful for concatenation in grouped rows)

```
insert into #TempTable (LetterID, LetterRow)
select
    min(L.LetterID) as LetterID,
    stuff(
        (
            select ' ' + T.LetterRow
            from LetterTable as T
            for xml path(''), type
        ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
   ,1,1, '') as LetterRow
from LetterTable as L
```

for one row you can also write this:

```
declare @LetterRow nvarchar(max), @LetterID int

select @LetterID = min(LetterID) from LetterTable
select @LetterRow = isnull(@LetterRow + ' ', '') + LetterRow from LetterTable

insert into #TempTable (LetterID, LetterRow)
select @LetterID, @LetterRow
```